# R Markdown HTML Overhead

Tags: javascript, html, r, r-markdown

My R Markdown generated html files have a huge overhead (~700-750 KB) even without any content on them. When I removed that overhead (actually I think it is javascript with some styling encoded in it in the head) my file size dropped to 2 KB and I lost some styling. A small sample of the code chunk is given below.

```
<script src="data:application/x-javascript;
base64,LyohIGpRdWVyeSB2MS4xMS4zIHwgKGMpIDIwMDUsIDIwMT...
```

I need to publish many pages (~1000 of them) Is it possible to remove or at least reduce the overhead size?

p.s. I did not try it yet; but if I convert to bookdown, is it possible that I can get a smaller aggregate size considering total size?

Comment: You can use `self_contained: false` in the YAML header. But you'll need to ensure that any files needed within the document are available on a relative path.

Comment: @Benjamin yes it worked but now i have to figure out a way to keep names similar but figures in a different folder:)